# spyder 4.1.5 cancel instant document(argument)?

Tags: spyder

It's very helpful. But for me I'd like a cleaner interface.
How to hide the instant documention? Is there a setting?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To hide that, please go to

`Tools > Preferences > Completion and linting > Introspection`

and deactivate the option called `Show calltips`.